# how to access different element then root element using this.$el

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

in my template I got this:

```
    <div v-show="showContent" class="content-block-body">
        <div class="slider-pro">
            <div class="sp-slides">
                <slide v-for="block in subItems"
                  :uniqueId="block.uniqueId"
                  v-bind="block.settings"
                  :container-preview="containerPreview"
                  :transparent-input-background="transparentInputBackground"
                  v-on:remove="removeBlock(block.uniqueId)"
                  :key="block.uniqueId">
                </slide>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am using a jquery plugin that needs to lock on

```
<div class="slider-pro">
```

tag. The following works If I remove first div:

```
        this.el = jQuery(this.$el)
        this.el.sliderPro()
```

but If I have that first div, plugin can not initialize correctly. How do I using this.$el find other div's inside the template so I can pass it correctly to the jQuery and then use that to initialize the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `ref` on that element.

```
<div class="slider-pro" ref="slider">
```

Then use the ref.

```
jQuery(this.$refs.slider)
```

Remember this will only work once the component has been rendered (in or after `mounted`).